How to Automatically Install or Copy Files from SD Card to New Raspberry Pi on First Boot?
have an SD card with Ubuntu installed, and it contains a project folder with some important files. When I insert this SD card into a new Raspberry Pi, is there a way to automatically copy or install everything from the SD card (including the project folder) into the Raspberry Pi's filesystem on first boot?
Ideally, I would like the Raspberry Pi to automatically handle the copying or installation without requiring manual intervention each time. What would be the best approach to achieve this?
Any suggestions or pointers on how to script or configure this setup would be greatly appreciated.
